# How easy is it to extract shared secret from source code

Tags: c#, .net

I want to encrypt a string and save it to disk in an encrpyted format.  To do this I'll have to place the shared secret somewhere in source code. How easy is it for the user to then extract this when the program is running? 
It's not the end of the world if they do but I'd prefer it if they can't see this string.
I'm using c# .net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Child's Play.Have you heard about Reflector.Its a Software that reads the ILCode and generates the source code.Getting the secret from the source code is like a walk in the park.
You can use the following security measures

**Obfuscating your code with String Encryption**

**Adding a custom installer action to store the secret encrypted using system specific key(DPAPI) in the app.config file**

Any method whatever be it, is not 100% crack proof.If you give the Executable publicly it can be reversed

Answer (score 1):

It's trivial for someone who has any idea what they are doing (that is: anyone who would be interested in 'hacking' your app in the first place). It'll prevent the most casual, non-technical users from being able to access the string in the disk file, but that's it.

Comment: Thanks Andrew-Do you have any better solutions to secure this string. I suppose it can always be pulled from memory no matter what I do, just don't want to make it too easy.

Comment: Didn't know you were on ASP.NET; Romil's answer should help you.

Comment: I'm on .net but the link Romil provided seems to indicate I can encrypt sections of an App.config as well as a web.config. Guess I'll find out soon ;-)

Comment: Running code on a server is a different thing than on a client desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Store the key in config file and encrypt the section of config file using aspnet_regiis utility.

[See full code to encrypt the config file](http://www.dotnetprofessional.com/blog/post/2008/03/03/Encrypt-sections-of-WebConfig-or-AppConfig.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Romil-This seems to be exactly what I need.

Comment: You can find out the same implementation on MSDN sites.

Comment: @Romil aspnet_regiis works only for web based apps.The encryption algorithms are System specific you cannot distribute a executable with a pre encrypted app.config file